# Access Violation using 'form.showmodal' method

Tags: delphi

I am trying to make a multiforms application by having only the main form created on start up and creating each new additional form dynamically as needed by creating that form object, using it as a modal and once that form's purpose is complete, it is freed from memory after it is closed. Only my main form is 'auto-created', all additional forms are set as 'available' in the the project options.

Here is sample code.

results form is declared as a global variable of TResultForm.

```
procedure TMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ResultsForm := TResultForm.Create(self);
  try
    ResultsForm.ShowModal;
  finally
    ResultsForm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The moment I call this method by clicking on the button, the Results form opens as it should, displays, but I recieve an access violation error:

'access violation at address 005B0291 in module 'MyApp.exe'. Read of address 00000000'.

On that form I have databases being linked to that form and displayed. Code for that works, no problems. Since trying this new sample code sourced from Embarcadero's help tool, only the controls on the new form (ResultForm) are loaded, no explicitly added code on that form initiates.

Comment: That code is fine. The problem lies elsewhere. Use the debugger. It will break at the line of code which raises the error. Then find out which pointer is `nil` and take it from there. You must learn to use the debugger to be able to fix problems like this.

Comment: in addition to David's comment, I would say to check what's assigned to TResultForm in OnShow, OnActivate, OnCreate and OnResize events.

Comment: maybe he has an onclose event with caFree?

Comment: A couple of questions: 1. Where is ResultSForm declared? As it isn't the same name as the default global that Delphi would create for TResultForm, I assume it is defined elsewhere. 2. Do any methods of TResultForm refer to ResultForm, rather than Self?

Comment: @whosrdaddy - I thought that myself (even started writing an answer), then re-read were Winston says `opens as it should, displays, but I recieve an access violation error:`

Comment: @GerryColl - indeed, misread that. Anyway we can't help without seeing the code from the resultsform...

Comment: @Winston It's pointless asking a question here and then ignoring all requests for more information. We can help you but only if you let us. It's all down to you.

Comment: Im going to guess its something in the ResultForm not your main form that isnt working, such as perhaps referencing a form not open..